# Mongoose $push into array adding _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema in a node.js app

```
(...)
numbers:{
    highest: Number,
    history:[{number: Number, date: Date}]
}
(...)
```

and I need to update this part, so I do (high, score and date being variables with a number, another number and a `New Date()`

```
Users.update({ 'name': user.name},
    { $set: { 'numbers.highest': high},
        $push: { 'numbers.history': { number: score, date: date}}
    }
```

So far, so good...but when I look in my collection I got an array with the two values (great) but also an `_id`. And this `_id` is the same of the document.

I tried making the same update on the mongo console and that worked just fine...no `_id`'s

Do you know what that can be? Cheers

Comment: @NeilLunn I tried to find something like that for like half an hour...thanks!

Comment: Your also the lucky third customer of the day. Anyhow. The topic is there even if you did not find it at first.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I know! :) I'm just glad you gave me the answer!